# Dynamically load HTML template in angular8 works but Binding a property to an interpolated string doesnt

Tags: angular, angular8

I am passing few html templates from server to angular through an Api. I am able to display the content of the html through innerhtml in angular dynamically by their respective name (dcName ). But i am NOT able to Bind a property to an interpolated string within the html string thats being passed to inner html.

Below is my angular component.html

```
<div [innerHtml]="dcData">
</div>
```

below is my component ts file

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.httpservice.getData("/api/getDc?dcName=" + this.dcName)
      .subscribe((html: string) => {
        this.dcData = html;
      });
      this.title = "Hello";
  }
```

This is the html content i am getting through api

```
<html>
<body>    
    <p>
      {{title}} Good morning!!
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the title to be replaced by hello

Comment: No possible in angular

Comment: not sure but seems this is not a valid way to bind value

Comment: Hi Scooby, if my answer helped you out, don't forget to mark it as accepted by clicking the gray checkmark below the vote on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that providing this built-in would encourage using patterns that could lead to cross-site security vulnerability. Instead you could:

```js
 ngOnInit() {
    this.httpservice.getData("/api/getDc?dcName=" + this.dcName)
      .subscribe((html: string) => {
        this.dcData = html;
      });
      this.title = "Hello";
  }

  getContent() {
    return this.dcData.replace("{{title}}", this.title);
  }
```

And in your component:

```html
<div [innerHtml]="getContent()">
</div>
```

Comment: Don't forget to initialize `dcData ` to an empty string, or `.replace` will error